# DropdownButton doesnt work in ListViewbuilder

Tags: flutter

I'll be so grateful.IF you can help me with this problem. got stuck for a day. code doesn't show the dropdowbutton menues when I click on them. It's a list of dropdownbuttons with their own items.I can see the list of dropdowns but when I click on them the menu doesn't showup . There are 2 lists on for the item list of dropdowns and the second list for the content of dropdowns

```
class PerfomersList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PerfomersListState createState() => _PerfomersListState();
}

class _PerfomersListState extends State<PerfomersList> {
  final String valuechoose;
  final europeanCountries = [
    'Category',
    'Availiblity',
    'From',
    'Instant Booking',
    'Pricing',
    'Rating',
  ];
  final dropdownlist = [
    'StandupComedian',
    'Funtalk',
    'Influencers',
    'Ventrgualizer',
    'Nature',
    'Dancers',
  ]; 

   
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                height: 100,
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.symmetric(
                    horizontal: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      width: .5,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                child: LIstOfItem(
                  europeanCountries: europeanCountries,
                  dropdownlist: dropdownlist,
                  valuechoose: valuechoose,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LIstOfItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> europeanCountries;
  final List<String> dropdownlist;
  final String valuechoose;

  const LIstOfItem({
    Key key,
    this.europeanCountries,
    this.dropdownlist,
    this.valuechoose,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LIstOfItemState createState() => _LIstOfItemState();
}

class _LIstOfItemState extends State<LIstOfItem> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: widget.europeanCountries.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Container(
          width: 210,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.white,
              width: .5,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
          ),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 9.0),
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 9.0, vertical: 20),
          child: DropdownButton(
            dropdownColor: Colors.green,
            hint: Text(widget.europeanCountries[index],
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
            items: widget.europeanCountries.map((valitem) {
              return DropdownMenuItem(
                child: Text(
                  valitem,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                value: valitem,
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of the `DropDownButton`,

> If [items] or [onChanged] is null, the button will be disabled, the down arrow will be greyed out.

Since, you haven't provided an `onChanged` parameter to your widget, it got automatically `disabled` which means you won't be able to click on it. This is why you are unable to see the options.

Add this,

```
child: DropdownButton(
  // Add this onChanged parameter
  onChanged: (String answer) {
    // the answer is the value of the option that has been chosen
    // you can use it to set a value in the state
  },
```

Comment: Really appreciate it , Man 

Comment: May I ask another question, How can I have different List of item for every dropdown menu in listviewbuilder??

Comment: May I ask another question, How can I have different List of item for every dropdown menu in listviewbuilder??

Comment: Could you elaborate what you want to achieve ? Do you want to have different set of options for each `DropDownButton` ? that's it right ?

Comment: Sure : WE have 4 dropdown buttons in the Listviewbuilder , In the code above all the dropdown menus have the same content ( dropdownlist) But Every dropdowbutton have its own list how show popolate a list of list in dropdown buttons

Comment: You need to maintain a map like this { "question_1_name": ["option1", "option2"], "question_2_name": ["option_a_1", "options_a_2" ] }. Then you can use this map to render different dropdowns and their values.

Comment: So this part of code : 

final dropdownlist = [
    'StandupComedian',
    'Funtalk',
    'Influencers',
    'Ventrgualizer',
    'Nature',
    'Dancers',
  ]; which contents of every menu should change to

Comment: final questionMap = [
    'Category':  [ 'StandupComedian', 'Funtalk', 'Influencers', 'Ventrgualizer', 'Nature', 'Dancers' ],
    'Availiblity': [],
    'From': [],
    'Instant Booking': [],
    'Pricing': [],
    'Rating': [],
  ];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232755/discussion-between-nisanth-reddy-and-dani-m).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `onChanged()` as Nishanth said here is your code with little tweak.
Your `ListOfItem()` widget

```
 class LIstOfItem extends StatefulWidget {
    final List<String> europeanCountries;
    final List<String> dropdownlist;
    String valuechoose; // Change your valuechoose from final to non final
  // Make your constructor non constant
    LIstOfItem({
      Key key,
      this.europeanCountries,
      this.dropdownlist,
      this.valuechoose,
    }) : super(key: key);
  
    @override
    _LIstOfItemState createState() => _LIstOfItemState();
  }
  
  class _LIstOfItemState extends State<LIstOfItem> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: widget.europeanCountries.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
         // it will hover to value which selected when dropdown poped up
         widget.valuechoose = widget.europeanCountries[index];
          return Container(
            width: 210,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(
                color: Colors.white,
                width: .5,
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
            ),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 9.0),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 9.0, vertical: 20),
            child: DropdownButton(
              value: widget.valuechoose, // add your valuechoose here
              dropdownColor: Colors.green,
              hint: Text(widget.europeanCountries[index],
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
              items: widget.europeanCountries.map((valitem) {
                return DropdownMenuItem(
                  child: Text(
                    valitem,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  value: valitem,
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (val) {
                // changing your valuechoose when user clicks item
                widget.valuechoose = val;
              },
            ),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you Chirag. Yes that was problem . Thank you

Comment: May I ask another question, How can I have different List of item for every dropdown menu in listviewbuilder??  Thank you